# Disable any non-user changes to screen window titles with zsh

Tags: macos, command-line, zsh, gnu-screen, oh-my-zsh

I upgraded my shell to ZSH recently on OS X and one behavior is driving me nuts. I've tried a few suggested fixes and haven't figured it out yet, so I figured I'd try here.

When I start a GNU screen session, I prefer to manually set the title of each window, and have those titles never change automatically. (I like doing all activities of one kind in one window: vim, git, make, etc.)

With zsh, I'm able to change the window title like normal (CTRL-A, Shift-A), but then as soon as I do any command in that window, the title is changed.

I've tried adding `DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"` to my `~/.zshrc` but to no avail. Any help? Thanks!

EDIT: I've got oh-my-zsh installed, so maybe this has something to do with that.

Comment: _zsh_ doesn't change the windows title by default. I suppose, you have something like _oh-my-zsh_ installed. Try with a clean shell, invoked by `zsh -f`.

Comment: @mpy, thanks I added an edit to note that I'm using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `screen` oh-my-zsh plugin ignores the `DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE` option: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/8449#issuecomment-561800791